# How to check focused dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my windows form, the controls are created dynamically. So now, in which form event can i check which control has the focus?

For example,i create 4 buttons dynamically on form load, after that if i click on one button other 3 should disappear.There is nothing else on the form.

Comment: You tagged c# and vb. Hopefully you are okay with either.

Comment: Did you get something to work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know what control has focus if you can handle it's click event. Create a single handler for all of the buttons. When the buttons are dynamically created, add the handler for them. This code might go in a loop where you create the buttons. Or you might make each of them explicitly. For example:

```
Dim newButton As New Button
AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf buttonClicked
```

Here's the handler:

```
Private Sub buttonClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Handle the click event here.
    Dim clickedButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    For Each c As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf c Is Button Then
            If Not c.Equals(clickedButton) Then
                c.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```